# Compare data in 2 columns with VBA or formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets with IDs, first and last name, extracted from two different databases.

I need to send the client a third sheet where it shows that **ID 32721** of sheet 1, is equivalent to **ID 32761** of sheet 2.

Make an **DE x FOR** all of this data.

How can I do this in excel? I have tried with formulas and I have not been able, is there any way to do this with VBA? If so, help me because I do not understand anything about VBA.

[image]

**Result**

I need to compare name + surname in both sheets and in a third sheet show the relationships between the IDs.

[image]

Comment: Tell is what formulae you tried and what is your desired output and how it looks like. Please add o/p screenshots

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but refer to code for Public Sub IOCountByColumn at [this url](https://github.com/Vandivier/data-science-practice/blob/master/vb/mUtilities.bas) for a start.

Comment: @GowthamShiva 
I tried using VLOOKUP, but I could not.
The ideal result would be to compare the first and last name and show that the ID x in one worksheet is the ID Y in another.

Comment: Paulo, please tell me if am right. Compare ID, first name, name in both the sheets, Filter which are common in both sheets (all 3 fields), then populate them in another sheet .

Comment: @GowthamShiva I think they want to compare first name and last name in the two sheets, but not ID - if there is a match then output ID from sheet 1 and ID from sheet 2 in sheet 3?

Comment: @SteveES Exact.

I need to compare name + surname in both sheets and in a third sheet show the relationships between the IDs.


I updated the question with an image of what would be the expected result.

Comment: @GowthamShiva 
I updated the question with an image of what would be the expected result.

Comment: Do you expect all entries in Sheet 1 to have a corresponding entry in Sheet 2 (and vice versa)?

Comment: @SteveES 
That's right

Comment: And those that do not have their pair, can appear alone in the report, to show me that on sheet 1 has the ID X that does not have the correspondent in sheet 2.

Comment: I fail to see how any of your sample data screenshots have **anything** to do with first and last name.

Comment: @Jeeped 
It's just a sampling of data, but the logic is the same, I need to buy the two columns row by row in two separate sheets.

Comment: If the first and last name are unique to the first two worksheets, simply put the first and last on the third worksheet and use `SUMIFS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution extracts to `Sheet3` the following:

1. Matching records and their relationship
2. Records in `Sheet1` not in `Sheet2`
3. Records in `Sheet2` not in `Sheet1`

**Assumptions:**
There is a different number of records in the sheets, and  the records are not sorted in both sheets. Records in `Sheet1` are located at `A1:C36` and records in `Sheet2` are located at `A1:C33`

**Formulas:**

1. Matching records and their relationship (located at `A1:D33`)

To extract the records that appear in both sheets use these formulas:

*Sheet1 ID (`FormulaArray` in column A):*

```
    =IFERROR( INDEX( ID.1,
    AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
    MATCH( Name.2 & LastName.2, Name.1 & LastName.1, 0 ),
    ROW() - ROW($1:$1) )), "")
```

*Name (Formula in column B):*

```
    =IFERROR( INDEX( Name.1, MATCH( $A2, ID.1, 0 )), "")
```

*Last Name (Formula in column C):*

```
    =IFERROR( INDEX( LastName.1, MATCH( $A2, ID.1, 0 )), "")
```

*Sheet2 ID (`FormulaArray` in column D):*

```
    =IFERROR( INDEX( ID.2, MATCH(
    INDEX( Name.1, MATCH( $A2, ID.1, 0 )) &
    INDEX( LastName.1, MATCH( $A2, ID.1, 0 )),
    Name.2 & LastName.2, 0 )), "")
```

2. Records in `Sheet1` not in `Sheet2` (located at `F1:H33`)

To extract the records that only appear in `Sheet1` use these formulas:

*Sheet1 ID (`FormulaArray` in column F):*

```
    =IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,
    IF(ISERROR(MATCH( Name.1 & LastName.1, Name.2 & LastName.2, 0 )), ID.1, ""),
    ROW() - ROW($1:$1)),"")
```

*Name (Formula in column G):*

```
    =IFERROR( INDEX( Name.1, MATCH( $F2, ID.1, 0 )), "")
```

*Last Name (Formula in column H):*

```
    =IFERROR( INDEX( LastName.1, MATCH( $F2, ID.1, 0 )), "")
```

3. Records in `Sheet2` not in `Sheet1` (located at `J1:L33`)
   To extract the records that only appear in `Sheet2` use these formulas:

*Sheet2 ID (`FormulaArray` in column J):*

```
    =IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,
    IF(ISERROR(MATCH( Name.2 & LastName.2, Name.1 & LastName.1, 0 )), ID.1, ""),
    ROW() - ROW($1:$1)),"")
```

*Name (Formula in column K):*

```
    =IFERROR( INDEX( Name.2, MATCH( $J2, ID.2, 0 )), "")
```

*Last Name (Formula in column L):*

```
    =IFERROR( INDEX( LastName.2, MATCH( $J2, ID.2, 0 )), "")
```

Where:

ID.1       = `Sheet1!$A$2:$A$36`

Name.1     = `Sheet1!$B$2:$B$36`

LastName.1 = `Sheet1!$C$2:$C$36`

ID.2       = `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$33`

Name.2     = `Sheet2!$B$2:$B$33`

LastName.2 = `Sheet2!$C$2:$C$33`

***`FormulaArrays`*** are entered pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

See [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df), [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd), [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use an `INDEX` `MATCH` [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) (hit `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`, rather than just `Enter`) in Sheet 1 to generate a list of IDs from Sheet 2. This [link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/#lookup-multiple-criteria) provides an excellent explanation of using `INDEX` `MATCH` on multiple criteria. (It will essentially do the same as `VLOOKUP`, but is more powerful). Your formula would look something like this:

```
{=INDEX('Sheet2'!$A$2:$C$13, MATCH(1, (B2='Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$13) * (C2='Sheet2'!$C$2:$C$13) ,0), 1)}
```

Where the above finds the row `MATCH` of B2 and C2 from Sheet1 in the ranges B2:B13 and C2:C13 respectively in Sheet2, then uses `INDEX` for that row and column 1 from Sheet2.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon on StackOverflow. Either reproduce the pertinent portions of the link or use the information to construct a parallel solution with the OP's data.

Comment: @Jeeped Edited to add the formula.

Comment: @SteveES 
I used here, adapting the name of the sheets and pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter and nothing happened

Comment: Did you put the formula in Sheet1 or Sheet3? If Sheet3, B2 and C2 would need to be 'Sheet1'!B2 and 'Sheet1'!C2. It is also possible it didn't find a match (can't remember off the top of my head if it gives an error or a blank value when no match is found). Also, in case you did, don't copy the curly brackets {}, these are put in when you hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter.